# no answer from dig (bind local zone file)

Tags: networking, 16.04, dns, bind

I don't understand why I get no answer from `dig` using local dns.

Here's my /etc/bind/db.myhome file :

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     myhome. root.myhome. (
                             37         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.myhome.
@       IN      A       192.168.1.1
ns.myhome IN    A       192.168.221.128
host1.myhome IN A       192.168.1.60
```

Here's my /etc/bind/named.conf.local :

```
zone "myhome" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.myhome";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.1.168.192";
};
```

I've incremented the serial, then did `rndc reload`.

If I then do `dig @localhost myhome` , I don't get an answer section.

What am I missing ?

Looking at `ifconfig`, 192.168.221.128  is my ip.

Looking at `systemctl status bind9`, I see this :

```
zone myhome/IN: not loaded due to errors.
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 7
all zones loaded
running
zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending notifies (serial 6)
network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
network unreachable resolving 'E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET/AAAA/IN': 2001:500:3::42#53
network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:3::42#53
network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:3::42#53
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because of ".myhome" here :

```
ns.myhome     IN    A       192.168.221.128
host1.myhome  IN    A       192.168.1.60
```

It works this way :

```
ns      IN    A       192.168.221.128
host1   IN    A       192.168.1.60
```

The tutorial where I learned that had the ".myhome" and it worked, so I guess he removed the "myhome" before actually testing it.